# How to install torch for cuda in Linux?

Tags: linux, software-installation, cuda

I would like to install pytorch for cuda, but getting had package conflicts. How to resolve this?

```
$ uname -r
3.10.0-1160.71.1.el7.x86_64

$ python -c "import torch; print(torch.version.cuda)"
None

$ nvidia-smi
Tue May  9 10:56:44 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.57.02    Driver Version: 470.57.02    CUDA Version: 11.4     |

$ python --version
Python 3.11.3

$ conda install -y pytorch==1.9

Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pytorch==1.9 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|3.6.12|3.6.12|3.7.10|3.7.10|3.7.12|3.8.12|3.8.16|3.9.16|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.11,<3.12.0a0|3.9.10|3.7.9|3.6.9|3.6.9|3.6.9|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|3.6.9|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*|>=3.8|3.8.*|>=3.7|>=3.6|>=3.5|3.9.*|3.7.*|>=3.6,<3.7',build='1_73_pypy|3_73_pypy|5_73_pypy|1_73_pypy|0_73_pypy|0_73_pypy|5_73_pypy|4_73_pypy|2_73_pypy|0_73_pypy']
  - pytorch==1.9 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0']

Your python: python=3.11

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.17=0
  - pytorch==1.9 -> __glibc[version='>=2.17|>=2.17,<3.0.a0']

Your installed version is: 2.17

Note that strict channel priority may have removed packages required for satisfiability.
```

Comment: you seem to be mixing a conda-installed python with your system python?

Comment: Thanks Marcus. Not sure. How do I check if that's the case? 'module avail pytorch` doesn't find any pytorch version.

Comment: never heard of `module`, so I'm even more confused than you. maybe you just want to set up a new clean conda environment directly for torch? https://pytorch.org says: `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.4 -c pytorch -c nvidia`

Comment: I tried this but got the same error.

Comment: You **did** create and activate an empty conda environment before, right?

Comment: Yes I created a new environment and activated and got the same error

Comment: OK, it looks like there is a conflict between python version and pytorch. But, not sure how to address the issue. Any ideas?